# How do I update a JTable that is an ArrayList?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable

I was testing an example code that lets people insert their names and the table will fill the name entered along with a seat number.

When the user presses the reserve seat button their name will be added to the table along with the seat number. Everything works except the seat number column. This is my problem I cannot figure out.

`int seatNum` is set to `1`. When the user presses the reserve button, Seat 1 is added to the array list. After that, I wrote to change `seatNum` to `seatNum+1`, but this code is ignored. The code will ignore changing the `seatNum`, which stops the array list from filling, after the code line
`seatResArr.set(seatNum, seatElement);`.

Can anyone explain how to change the `seatNum`? If not, please link me a forum with a similar problem as me.

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
public class SeatReservationFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
       private JTextField firstNameField;             // Holds first name
       private JFormattedTextField seatNumField;      // Holds seat number
       private JLabel tableLabel;                     // Label for table display
       private JLabel seatNumLabel;                   // Label for seat number
       private JLabel firstNameLabel;                 // Label for first name
       private JButton reserveButton;                 // Triggers seat reservation
       private JButton quitButton;                    // Triggers termination of GUI
       private JTable seatStatusTable;                // Table tracks seat 
reservations
       private final static int NUM_SEATS = 5;        // Number of seat in reservation system
       private static ArrayList<SeatInfo> seatResArr; // ArrayList of Seat objects

       /* Constructor creates GUI components and adds GUI components
          using a GridBagLayout. */
       SeatReservationFrame() {
          Object[][] tableVals = new Object[5][2];                // Seat reservation table
          String[] columnHeadings = {"Seat Number", "First Name", // Column headings for reservation table
                                     };
          GridBagConstraints layoutConst = null;                  // GUI component layout
     
          // Set frame's title
          setTitle("Seat reservation");

          // Add 5 seat objects to ArrayList
          seatResArr = new ArrayList<SeatInfo>();
          seatsAddElements(seatResArr, NUM_SEATS);

          // Make all seats empty
          seatsMakeEmpty(seatResArr);

          // Create seat reservation table
          tableLabel = new JLabel("Seat reservation status:");
          seatNumLabel = new JLabel("Seat Number:");
          firstNameLabel = new JLabel("First Name:");

          seatNumField = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance());
          seatNumField.setEditable(false);
          seatNumField.setValue(0);

          firstNameField = new JTextField(20);
          firstNameField.setEditable(true);
          firstNameField.setText("John");

          reserveButton = new JButton("Reserve");
          reserveButton.addActionListener(this);

          quitButton = new JButton("Quit");
          quitButton.addActionListener(this);

          // Initialize table
          seatStatusTable = new JTable(tableVals, columnHeadings);
          seatStatusTable.setEnabled(false); // Prevent user input via table

          // Add components using GridBagLayout
          setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

          layoutConst = new GridBagConstraints();
          layoutConst.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 1, 0);
          layoutConst.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
          layoutConst.gridx = 0;
          layoutConst.gridy = 0;
          add(tableLabel, layoutConst);

          layoutConst = new GridBagConstraints();
          layoutConst.insets = new Insets(1, 10, 0, 0);
          layoutConst.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
          layoutConst.gridx = 0;
          layoutConst.gridy = 1;
          layoutConst.gridwidth = 4;
          add(seatStatusTable.getTableHeader(), layoutConst);

          layoutConst = new GridBagConstraints();
          layoutConst.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 10, 0);
          layoutConst.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
          layoutConst.gridx = 0;
          layoutConst.gridy = 2;
          layoutConst.gridwidth = 4;
          add(seatStatusTable, layoutConst);

          layoutConst = new GridBagConstraints();
          layoutConst.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 1, 0);
          layoutConst.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
          layoutConst.gridx = 0;
          layoutConst.gridy = 3;
          add(seatNumLabel, layoutConst);

          layoutConst = new GridBagConstraints();
          layoutConst.insets = new Insets(1, 10, 10, 0);
          layoutConst.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
          layoutConst.gridx = 0;
          layoutConst.gridy = 4;
          add(seatNumField, layoutConst);

          layoutConst = new GridBagConstraints();
          layoutConst.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 1, 0);
          layoutConst.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
          layoutConst.gridx = 1;
          layoutConst.gridy = 3;
          add(firstNameLabel, layoutConst);

          layoutConst = new GridBagConstraints();
          layoutConst.insets = new Insets(1, 10, 10, 0);
          layoutConst.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
          layoutConst.gridx = 1;
          layoutConst.gridy = 4;
          add(firstNameField, layoutConst);


          layoutConst = new GridBagConstraints();
          layoutConst.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 10, 5);
          layoutConst.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
          layoutConst.gridx = 4;
          layoutConst.gridy = 4;
          add(reserveButton, layoutConst);

          layoutConst = new GridBagConstraints();
          layoutConst.insets = new Insets(0, 5, 10, 10);
          layoutConst.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
          layoutConst.gridx = 5;
          layoutConst.gridy = 4;
          add(quitButton, layoutConst);
       }

       /* Called when either button is pressed. */
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
          SeatInfo seatElement;  // Seat information
          String firstName;      // First name
          int seatNum;           // Seat number

          // Get source of event (2 buttons in GUI)
          JButton sourceEvent = (JButton) event.getSource();

          // User pressed the reserve button
          if (sourceEvent == reserveButton) {
             seatNum = 1;
                firstName = firstNameField.getText();

                seatElement = new SeatInfo();         // Create new Seat object
                seatElement.reserveSeat(firstName);
                seatResArr.set(seatNum, seatElement); // Add seat to ArrayList
                updateTable();                        // Synchronize table with sts ArrayList
                
              seatNum = 4;  //!!!!! this code does not work. how can I change the array number?
                
                // Show success dialog
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "test");
             
          }
          else if (sourceEvent == quitButton) {
             dispose();                               // Terminate program
          }
       }

       /* Updates the reservation information displayed by the table */
       public void updateTable() {
          final int seatNumCol = 0;   // Col num for seat numbers
          final int firstNameCol = 1; // Col num for first names
          final int lastNameCol = 2;  // Col num for last names
          final int paidCol = 3;      // Col num for amount paid
          int i;                      // Loop index

          for (i = 0; i < NUM_SEATS && i < seatResArr.size(); ++i) {
             if (seatResArr.get(i).isEmpty()) { // Clear table entries 
                seatStatusTable.setValueAt(null, i, seatNumCol);
                seatStatusTable.setValueAt(null, i, firstNameCol);
             }
             else {                             // Update table with content in the seatResArr ArrayList
                seatStatusTable.setValueAt(i, i, seatNumCol);
                seatStatusTable.setValueAt(seatResArr.get(i).getFirstName(), i, firstNameCol);
             }
          }
       }

       /* Makes seats empty */
       public static void seatsMakeEmpty(ArrayList<SeatInfo> seatsRes) {
          int i;      // Loop index
          
          for (i = 0; i < seatsRes.size(); ++i) {
             seatsRes.get(i).makeEmpty();
          }
       }

       /* Adds empty seats to ArrayList */
       public static void seatsAddElements(ArrayList<SeatInfo> seatsRes, int numSeats) {
          int i;     // Loop index
          
          for (i = 0; i < numSeats; ++i) {
             seatsRes.add(new SeatInfo());
          }
       }

       /* Creates a SeatReservationFrame and makes it visible */
       public static void main(String[] args) {
              // Creates SeatReservationFrame and its components
              SeatReservationFrame myFrame = new SeatReservationFrame();

              myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
              myFrame.pack();
              myFrame.setVisible(true);
           }
  }
```

This is the second class that holds the names entered:

```
public class SeatInfo {
   private String firstName; // First name

   // Method to initialize Seat fields
   public void reserveSeat(String inFirstName) {
      firstName = inFirstName;
   }

   // Method to empty a Seat
   public void makeEmpty() {
      firstName = "empty";
   }

   // Method to check if Seat is empty
   public boolean isEmpty() {
      return firstName.equals("empty");
   }

   // Method to print Seat fields
   public void printSeatInfo() {
      System.out.print(firstName + " ");
   }

   public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
   }
 }
```

Comment: **Don't update the ArrayList directly**. The TableModel stores the data for the JTable. If you want to change the data you change the TableModel. The ArrayList is only used to store the data in the TableModel. So methods of the TableModel will update the ArrayList. See [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for an example of how to create a TableModel using the ArrayList to hold all the data.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I will read it and try out the example given

Comment: `int seatNum` is the variable of interest, right? It is declared within the scope of an `actionPerformed` method and is lost at the end of it. Instead, declare `seatNum` as an attribute of the  `SeatReservationFrame` and it should be created once when the class is constructed *and* retain its value between calls to the action performed method.

Comment: Moving SeatNum works! Thank you so much.